# Why can we invoke a method of an object from another thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, oop

I was reading a simple multi-threaded chatroom in Java. In the program, there's a class called `Chatroom`, which has method `broadcast`. The method was called by another `serverThread` thread, and it printed some messages in the original thread (the chatroom thread).

I am totally confused by this. My questions are:

1. How is it even possible to just call a method from another thread just like that? Don't we have to do some kind of "signal" or putting something into a shared data space so that methods in another thread can spontaneously act accordingly?
2. Even if it is possible. Why does it output not in the caller thread but in the thread in which it is defined?
3. A more general questions is I guess: how are code translated and executed in case of multi-threading? OOP just makes things a lot more confusing for me. (if you can point me to more resources to look at, I would be incredibly grateful)

Java Code

```java
public class ChatRoom {

    private ArrayBlockingQueue<ServerThread> serverThreads; // List<ChatRoom.ServerThread>

    // Entrance of the place
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        new ChatRoom(6789);
    }

    public ChatRoom(int port)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Binding to port " + port);
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            serverThreads = new ArrayBlockingQueue<ServerThread>(5); // new ArrayList<>();
            while(true)
            {
                Socket s = ss.accept();   //  Accept the incoming request
                System.out.println("Connection from " + s + " at " + new Date());
                ServerThread st = new ServerThread(s, this); //connection handler
                System.out.println("Adding this client to active client list");
                serverThreads.add(st);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Server shut down unexpectedly.");
            return;
        }

    }

    public void broadcast(String message)
    {
        if (message != null) {
            System.out.println("broadcasting ..." + message);
            for(ServerThread threads : serverThreads)
                    threads.sendMessage(message);
        }
    }

}


public class ServerThread extends Thread {

    private PrintWriter pw;
    private BufferedReader br;
    private ChatRoom cr;
    private Socket s;

    public ServerThread(Socket s, ChatRoom cr)
    {
        this.s = s;
        this.cr = cr;
        try
        {
            pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            start();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message)
    {
        pw.println(message);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try {
            while(true)
            {
                String line = br.readLine();
                //if(line == null) break; // client quits
                cr.broadcast(line);   // Send text back to the clients
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
        finally {
            try {
                pw.close();
                br.close();
                s.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
        }//finally
    }//run
}
```

And here is the output. It seems to me that the "broadcasting messages" are printed not in `ServerThread` thread (which btw I don't know how to show the output of), but in `Chatroom` Thread

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkSJt.png)

Comment: `ServerThread st = new ServerThread(s, this); ` - `this` is refering to an instance of a `ChatRoom` Object.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Hi! That part I did understand. But I don't see why it is printed on the Chatroom Thread. Let me update the question to add outputs.

Comment: Yes, you absolutely do have to do some kind of signal or something to talk between threads *safely*. Though the system won't stop you from ignoring all of the safeguards and just going wild west. Sort of like how you need a seatbelt to drive safely, but the laws of physics don't constrain you from driving without one.

Comment: Objects live on the heap, not the stack, which means they don't belong to any particular thread.  If a thread has a reference to an object, it can call that object's methods (within the usual access rules).  Local variables, of course, live on the stack, which means they belong to a particular thread.  But a local variable can never be an object - only a reference to an object.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Love your analogy! Thanks!

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Hi! Thanks for the hint. So I understand now that I can call a method of an object defined in any thread (because they are not linked to any particular one). But to which output (as you can see in the "output" image, there are 3 windows, 1 for Chatroom thread and 2 for ClientThread thread.) does the method print?  The caller of that method is "ServerThread thread" which is created by "Chatroom" thread. But as you can see, the window/output is only showing "Chatroom" but not any "ServerThread".

Comment: Often, the best way to answer a question like "what will happen if I do XYZ" is to do XYZ and see what happens.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I am grateful for your help and definitely willing to try, but I am not sure how. Allow me to clarify my question: 1. is there only one stdout that all threads print to? 2. when calling an object's method in a thread, does all of its code get executed as if they are "inside" that thread?

Comment: OK after some testing, I figured out that this method is indeed being called at the "ServerThread" created by "Chatroom". The printing together, I suspect, is because the the two threads are using the same stdout.

Comment: Yes, there is just one `stdout`.  And yes, any method calls you make will execute in the same thread as you call them.  Objects don't belong to threads; calling a method happens in a thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The method was called by another serverThread thread, and it printed some messages *in* the original thread (the chatroom thread).

This is a somewhat misleading statement depending on what you mean by the word "in".  Each of the `ServerThread` objects gets passed the `ChatRoom` object and are calling back to the `ChatRoom.broadcast(...)` method.  Don't be confused by them being threads.  This is just one object calling a method on the other.

> Why does it output not in the caller thread but in the thread in which it is defined?

Because it is the *caller* thread which is making the call.  Just because you are calling back and forth between the thread methods doesn't mean that different threads are making the calls.  The exercise is trying to be confusing.  Again, these are just objects calling other objects and there is no magic thread signaling going on here.

> how are code translated and executed in case of multi-threading?

Code works the same way in Java OOP regardless if you have multiple threads or not.  If ThreadA is running and calls `chatRoom.broadcast("foo")` then it is ThreadA which executes that method.  If that method turns around and makes a bunch of calls to each of the `serverThread.sendMessage(foo)` then it is still ThreadA which is running and making those method calls.  You actually have to do a lot of work to hand off control between threads.

> How is it even possible to just call a method from another thread just like that? Don't we have to do some kind of "signal" or putting something into a shared data space so that methods in another thread can spontaneously act accordingly?

Just because the one thread calls a method on the other does not in any way imply that there any signaling or automatic data sharing.  It depends highly on what data is being accessed.

Let's look at every part of the calls.  ThreadA calls back to `chatroom.broadCast(...)`.  In that method `message` is ok to be accessed because it is passed in, `System.out.println(...)` is a `synchronized` `PrintStream` which is also ok so it can be used, and the `ArrayBlockingQueue` is also `synchronized` so that works.  There are no unprotected fields from `Chatroom` being accessed.  Then you have to evaluate the call back to `ServerThread.sendMessage(...)` which uses a `PrintWriter` which is has an internal lock.  So this is kosher.  Again, if there was some access of a field that was local to each of the `ServerThread` objects, it would need to be locked somehow.

> OOP just makes things a lot more confusing for me.

I think it is the *question* which is designed to be confusing in this case  I assume it is an academic exercise.  In terms of how you can figure out what it is doing, I would print out `Thread.currentThread().getId()` so you can see *which* thread is printing what.  I would also reduce the number of threads and then scale it back up until you can follow it.

Going line by line and remembering that threads don't hand off control to other threads without specific calls that you would see.

**WARNING:** there are a couple of bugs in the exercise that should be fixed.  Hopefully the following doesn't confuse you because this is somewhat varsity thread stuff.

1. All of the fields in the `ServerThread` should be marked as `final`.  [`final` forces the fields to be fully initialized](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_final.shtml) before the `ServerThread` constructor finishes.  This is very important because each thread is accessing the `PrintWriter` of the other threads and might access fields in other threads before they are properly setup.  Yeah this is crazy stuff but part of the language definition.  For that matter, it would be a good pattern to have `Chatroom.serverThreads` also be `final`.  Anything initialized in the constructor should be `final` if possible.
2. As a rule and a continuation to the previous point, you should [never `start()` a thread inside it's own constructor](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-constructor).  You run the risk of having other threads access the fields in the thread before they are fully initialized.  Constructing the object and then calling `start()` on it outside of the constructor is the right thing to do.
3. The `Chatroom` object also is doing too much in its constructor.  It should not be creating the other threads in its constructor which then call back to the `Chatroom` which might not be initialized.  Constructing the socket and the `serverThreads` should be in the constructor but the `while` loop which creates the new server threads should be done in another method after the constructor finishes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Greetings! Thank you so much for the detailed walkthrough. It is indeed from an Intro to Java course I am taking, and this code is given to demonstrate socket (but I was confused by the multi-threading part obviously).  And thank you for pointing out the better way to start threads.

Comment: It's hard stuff @YuxingZhou.  Best of luck with it.  It's not an easy exercise but you should point out the bugs to your teacher so they can tweak the example.

Comment: The WARNING part contains some information which isn't correct. There is a happens before edge between the start of a thread and the run method being called on that thread. So all the changes made on ServerThread from the 'main thread' will be visible once the ServerThread runs. So the fields don't need to be made final for the sake of preventing data-races.

Comment: Yeah you are correct.  It's the other threads in the list that are at risk.  I'll edit.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> is there only one stdout that all threads print to?

`System` is the name of a class, and `System.out` is the name of a `static` member of that class. There can be only one `System.out` object—a `PrintStream` object—at any given point in time.

Normally, the Java runtime environment sets up `System.out` to point to some useful place such as a console window. But `System.out` is not `final`, so your program (or some library called by your program*) potentially could reassign it to send output somewhere else.

> when calling an object's method in a thread, does all of its code get executed as if they are "inside" that thread?

Yes. That's what threads do. They execute your code. Each thread starts executing your code in the `run()` method of some `Runnable` instance, and it continues to do whatever your code tells it to do from that point on until either (a) it reaches the end of the `run()` method, or (b) it throws an exception that is not caught.

I would not say "inside" though. A thread is not a container. There's nothing "inside" a thread, though there usually are some variables (e.g., all of the local variables of all of the functions that the thread calls) that other threads either do not or cannot access.

---

* It is *possible* for a library to do that, but it would be a really rude thing for the library to do unless the documentation  was *very* clear about what would happen.

Comment: That's super clear! Thank you so much.

Comment: There is a small inaccuracy in your answer.  In fact, `System.out` *is* `final`.  You can't change it by simply assigning to it.  Instead, there is a special method called `System.setOut` that can be used to modify it.  (`System.{in,out.err}` actually get a special mention in the JLS as being cases where changing a `final` has a *defined* behavior.)  But you are 100% correct that it is **rude** for a library to mess with the those variables.

Comment: @StephenC, That's new. I don't know since when. I know that as recently as JDK11, `out`, and `in`, and `err` were not `final`, but you're right. In the newest version they all are `final`.

Comment: No. It isn't new.  `System.out` etc have been `final` since Java 1.0.  And most likely since when the language was called Oak. Here's a link to the Java 1.1 javadoc: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall97/cs461/jdkdocs/api/java.lang.System.html#out

Comment: @StephenC, You're right. I was fooled by the Java11 API docs: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html. If you look at the declaration at the top of the doc, it doesn't say `final`. But, if you scroll down to the detailed description, it _does_ say `final`. Needless to say, I've never actually tried to write a Java program that reassigned `System.out`... Until just now, in a Java 11 SE JDK. And, big surprise, the compiler did not allow me to do it.